# python says module 'textwrap' has no attribute 'fill'

Tags: python, word-wrap

just learning a few modules in python from python 3 module of the week. When I was trying the module textwrap

```
import textwrap

sample_text = '''
    The textwrap module can be used to format text for output in
    situations where pretty-printing is desired.  It offers
    programmatic functionality similar to the paragraph wrapping
    or filling features found in many text editors.
    '''

textwrap.fill(sample_text, width=70)
```

it says: `module 'textwrap' has no attribute 'fill'`

tried

```
dedented_text = textwrap.dedent(sample_text)
print('Dedented:')
print(dedented_text)
```

it also says `module 'textwrap' has no attribute 'dedent'`

how come? I am using python 3.6

Comment: Is your script named `textwrap.py` perhaps?

Comment: actually yes.....

Comment: change it to something else and rerun.

Comment: I got it....that's why....